# Flutter web: Error when changing the RenderRepaintBoundary to image

Tags: image, flutter-web

I got this error when I used the RepaintBoundary widget and changed it to image by

```
final boundary = _repaintBoundaryKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject()
        as RenderRepaintBoundary?;
    final image = await boundary?.toImage(); 

Error: Assertion failed: org-dartlang-sdk:///flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/html/scene_builder.dart:94:16
matrix4[0] == window.devicePixelRatio &&
            matrix4[5] == window.devicePixelRatio
```

I find the cause of this error that is

```
final image = await boundary?.toImage();
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I found this on Github and forgot to close this.
Just build with `flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit`.

Comment: what if I can't use canvaskit instead of html due to NetworkImage() widget

Comment: Hi @AbdulQadir, I tried using this with `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit` and it works successfully. What is an error message?

```

Container(
              width: 300.0,
              height: 500.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  image: const DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(
                        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547721064-da6cfb341d50",
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
            ),

```

Answer (score 0):

Seems .toImage() is not yet implemented on web!
[GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42767)

But maybe you can try to run your code using canvakit renderer:
`flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer=canvaskit`